# swiping view or layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I'm trying to make an extra effect to menu that will come down from the top of the screen

I want to make it enter the screen while swiping it from the top and if the user left it, it should continue to the end

this is the figure that demonstrate what I want to do:

[image]

I tried to do it with animation but the animation will not go on while swiping and it will go to the end without touching

any other ideas to move the view down with finger ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK

It works for me now

I used `SlidingTray.java` class from this API

[API Website](http://aniqroid.sileria.com/doc/api/)

btw : this api open source

Answer (score 1):

Check this out for a sliding Drawer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html

it sound like you kind of want the same thing as the pulldown menu at the top of all android phones except you want it customized, the link will show you that.

Comment: I wasn't even know about SlidingDrawer before you told me.... Thanks alot you helped me alot